# Using Let inside of a if statement

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I am writing a code fragment that takes an element in a list and creates a variable with its absolute value. The problem is that DrRacket does not like like how I am using Let. 
let: bad syntax (missing binding pairs or body) in: (let ((abs (car l))))

```
(define abs
  (lambda (l)
    (if(>= (car l) 0)
       (let 
           ((abs(car l))))
       (let 
           ((abs(- car l)))))

    )
  )
```

Thank you

Comment: `let` created a local variable, and you can use that variable inside the body of the `let`. Neither of your `let` expressions have a body where you use the variable `abs`.

Comment: Also, `(- car l)` should be `(- (car l))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `let` forms have no body in which the variable `abs` is used.

Using two `let` expressions is also probably not what you want. You should use one, and then use `if` when calculating the value to bind the variable to.

```
(define abs
  (lambda (l)
    (let ((val (if (>= (car l) 0)
                   (car l)
                   (- (car l)))))
      val)
    )
  )
```